# Asp.Net Web Api custom event is always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, wpf

I have an Asp.Net Web Api project and a Wpf project (referenced to the Asp.net project) in the same solution, both are StartUp projects. I want to raise an event on the Get action of the aps.net Controller and open a Wpf window. The problem is that always the event is null even though I have subscribed to it.
Any ideas?  Here is my code:

```
public class CallController : ApiController
{
    public static event EventHandler CallIn;
    public void Get()
    {
        OnCallIn();           
    }

    private void OnCallIn()
    {
        CallIn(this, new EventArgs()); //CallIn is always null
    }
}

public partial class frmClients : Window
{
   private void Clients_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       CallController.CallIn +=  CallController_CallIn;
   }

   private void CallController_CallIn(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       frmLinkPopUp linkPop = new frmLinkPopUp();
       linkPop.Show();
   }
}
```

Comment: Is `frmclients` loaded when when the event is raised?

Comment: frmClients is loaded on startup. When the event is raised frmClients is already loaded.

Comment: Is the CallController inside frmClients an object of CallController class?

Comment: It seems very unlogic to have a *web* api trigger a *wpf* window to open. Anway, events in ApiControllers is not a good practice as controllers are instantiated per request. I suggest looking at another notification system like signalr (which can be self hosted as well)